# Is there a way to hide part of a URL created from the Wagtail admin page tree?

Tags: django, wagtail

Let's say I've created a blog for my website. The tree structure setup in the Wagtail admin looks like this:

Homepage > Blog Index > Blog Post

Is it possible to keep the Blog Index page in the admin page tree but remove it from the URL so that my URL's look like this:

Homepage > Blog Post

I am assigning a custom group to the Blog Index page which allows them to edit only Blog Posts that they have created, which is why Blog Index needs to stay in the tree on the admin side.

I've done a little work with the routablepagemixin but not to eliminate anything from the URL, only add to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain if a `RoutablePageMixin` is the right way to go about this, but that's how I've solved this before.

Here's an example of how you could do it with a `RoutablePageMixin` and a `route` (Note: I chopped this together pretty quickly and didn't test it, you might need to do some adjusting)

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models import RoutablePageMixin, route
from wagtail.core.models import Page

from blog.models import BlogPage


class HomePage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    """A home page class."""

    # HomePage Fields here...

    # This route will collect the blog slug
    # We'll look for the live BlogPost page.
    @route(r"^(?P<blog_slug>[-\w]*)/$", name="blog_post")
    def blog_post(self, request, blog_slug, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # Get the blog page
            blog_page = BlogPage.objects.live().get(slug=blog_slug)
        except BlogPage.DoesNotExist:
            # 404 or post is not live yet
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        except Exception:
            # Handle your other exceptions here; here's a simple redirect back to home
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

        # Additional logic if you need to perform something before serving the blog post

        # Let the blog post page handle the serve
        return blog_page.specific.serve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

One other thing to note: you'll want to change the sitemap url on your original blog post pages so they don't show up as `/blog/blog-slug/` inside of `sitemap.xml`.

Comment: Thanks @Kalob, it worked pretty much as posted. The only issue I had was that the HttpResponseRedirect needs to go above all the others. Didn't realize that at first. I ended changing my mind however as even though this works the old URL is still available whether accessing it directory or from within the Wagtail admin. That will end up confusing the users. Instead I'll find a way to use the blog index page for some useful content. Also, much thanks for your video tutorials at [https://learnwagtail.com](https://learnwagtail.com). They have been a great help!

Comment: You could overwrite the `serve()` method on the original page models to redirect to this routable page as well. This ends up becoming a lot of work I find. Another option is to just put your blog posts under the Home Page and leverage wagtails page searching once you have a lot of pages. Glad you're finding the videos helpful!! :)

Comment: I was wanting to do this same thing, but decided not to because it just felt too hacky. I think it would be a great feature to be able to organize your content in different folders in the admin, while having the flexibility for them to have their own URL patterns.